# Adding to 2d dict not working as expected (python)

Tags: python, dictionary

Im creating a function that returns a 2d dictionary, however, when adding the second part of the inner dict, it overwrites the first part and they both become the same value.

It will become more clear by reading the following:

```
# variables from other part of my code
int_col = [1,3]

data = [['CJ', '20', 'Male', '20000'], \
        ['Auts', '21', 'Female', '25000'], \
        ['Lucy', '20', 'Female', '10000'], \
        ['Lily', '20', 'Female', '15000']]

header = ['Name', 'Age', 'Sex', 'Salary']

# returns dict on numerical values in data
def stats():
    stats_dict = {}
    col_stats = {}

    # loops through int_col 
    for col in int_col:
        max_int = -1000000
        min_int = 1000000

        # loops through data
        for row in data:
            # converts str items to int
            # done differerently in my code
            row[col] = int(row[col])
            if isinstance(row[col], int):

                if row[col] > max_int:
                    max_int = row[col]
                
                if row[col] < min_int:
                    min_int = row[col]

        # fills one dict to be added to another
        col_stats["max"] = max_int
        col_stats["min"] = min_int

        # adds first dict to outer dict
        stats_dict[header[col]] = col_stats
        
        print(stats_dict)
    return stats_dict


stats()
```

I expect stats_dict to be:
`{'Age': {'max': 21, 'min': 20},, 'Salary': {'max': 25000, 'min': 10000}}`

however, it looks like this:
`'Age': {'max': 25000, 'min': 10000}, 'Salary': {'max': 25000, 'min': 10000}}`

I was wondering what I was doing wrong and how to get the expected output?

Thanks,
CJ

Comment: There is only *one* `col_stats` dict; you keep modifying it, and adding references to that one dict to `stats_dict`.  You need to create a new `col_stats` on each iteration of your loop.

Comment: You ca try moving your `col_stats = {}` declaration from where it is to inside the first for loop

Comment: As mentioned above, you must create a single `col_stats` variable in order to expand your code and get the desired results and accommodate the variables like *age year max min etc* **`H M T Y`**..., otherwise the output of your program will be redirected in the wrong way or it just doesn't fit.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you use the same `col_stats` twice.

It becomes clear if you have a bit of tracing :

```
+                print(f"comparing {row[col]=!r} > {max_int}")
                 if row[col] > max_int:
                     max_int = row[col]
+                    print(f"{max_int=!r}")

+                print(f"comparing {row[col]=!r} < {min_int}")
                 if row[col] < min_int:
                     min_int = row[col]
+                    print(f"{min_int=!r}")
```

```py
comparing row[col]=20 > -1000000
max_int=20
comparing row[col]=20 < 1000000
min_int=20
comparing row[col]=21 > 20
max_int=21
comparing row[col]=21 < 20
comparing row[col]=20 > 21
comparing row[col]=20 < 20
comparing row[col]=20 > 21
comparing row[col]=20 < 20
{'Age': {'max': 21, 'min': 20}}
comparing row[col]=20000 > -1000000
max_int=20000
comparing row[col]=20000 < 1000000
min_int=20000
comparing row[col]=25000 > 20000
max_int=25000
comparing row[col]=25000 < 20000
comparing row[col]=10000 > 25000
comparing row[col]=10000 < 20000
min_int=10000
comparing row[col]=15000 > 25000
comparing row[col]=15000 < 10000
{'Age': {'max': 25000, 'min': 10000}, 'Salary': {'max': 25000, 'min': 10000}}
```

The calculations are indeed correct.

But what happens after is the error :

```py
        col_stats["max"] = max_int
        col_stats["min"] = min_int
        stats_dict[header[col]] = col_stats
```

The first time it will add two entries (`max: 21` and `min: 21`) to the `col_stats` dict, and add one entry to `stats_dict["Age"]`. Ok.
The second time it will change the two entries of the same `col_stats` dictionary, thus changing what is accessible through `stats_dict["Age"]`.

Your problem is you have mutable data, and you mutated it unintentionally.

One easy solution is to copy the `col_stats` :

```py
        stats_dict[header[col]] = col_stats.copy()
```

But you can also simply do not share the same dict :

```py
# remove the declaration earlier
# [...]

+        col_stats = {}  # A NEW DICT !
         col_stats["max"] = max_int
         col_stats["min"] = min_int
```

Beware of sharing mutable data !